# How to print object from within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple class I created:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
```

and I want to print a list of objects from this class using a function I created:

```
def p(s):
    print('hi ', s)
```

This is how I want to call the printing function `p`: `p([C() for i in range(3)])`

Unfortunately, this produces `hi  [<__main__.C object at 0x000000F92A8B9080>, <__main__.C object at 0x000000F92AB0E898>, <__main__.C object at 0x000000F92AB0E978>]`.

I thought the problem was due to not implementing `__str__` so I changed my class into:

```
class C:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.a)
```

but I get the same result :(

What I hoped for was `hi [1, 1, 1]` or `hi 1, 1, 1` or something like that, not the memory location of the objects I created.

I can use

`for i in range(3):
    p(C())`

but I want to pass a list of objects to the `p` function rather than call it for each of my objects. Is that possible?

Comment: You need to implement `__repr__`, the `__str__` for `list` uses the `__repr__` of the objects it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `__str__` with `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.a)
```